# Оптимизация кода C/C++

Tags: c, оптимизация, c++

Какой код будет выполнятся быстрее при многократном вызове, будет ли VS2010 что-нибудь оптимизировать ?

1)

```
int Function(){
   int Var;
   Var=2*2;
   return (Var);
}
```

2)

```
int Function(){
   static int Var;
   Var=2*2;
   return (Var);
}
```

3)

```
int Function(){
   return (2*2);
}
```

Второй вопрос, что эффективней разыменование или обращение по индексу!?

Третий вопрос, в нижеприведённом коде можно ли что нибудь оптимизировать или он совершенен !? :)

```
unsigned long Time2Sec(unsigned char *pbTimeString){
        unsigned long dwResult;
        dwResult=((*pbTimeString-'0')*10+(*(pbTimeString+1)-'0'))*3600+
                 ((*(pbTimeString+3)-'0')*10+(*(pbTimeString+4)-'0'))*60+
                 ((*(pbTimeString+6)-'0')*10+(*(pbTimeString+7)-'0'));
        return (dwResult);
}
```

Четвёртый вопрос, что работает быстрее (по условию задачи - один оператор if исключает другой)

4.1)

```
if (условие_1) ...
if (условие_2) ...
```

4.2)

```
if (условие_1) ...
else if (условие_2) ...
```

Comment: в идеале - a[x] равносильно *(a+x*sizeof(element_a)). исходя из этого и думайте.

Comment: Что в вашем понимании "Расстрел памяти"? В данном коде я произвожу только чтение из памяти и что может произойти если даже залезу не туда!?

Comment: от просто неверного значения до синего экрана. Смотря, какой указатель туда передадите.
"Расстрел памяти" - это когда читают и пишут по адресам, по которым этому коду бы не следовало.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда как должен выглядеть код на ваш взгляд!?

Comment: @reije, по поводу идексация или указатель? Обычно оптимизатор делает одинаковый код. 

Не знаю, совершенен ли код третьего вопроса, но глядя на ассемблер, производимый `gcc -O3 -S` я не понимаю, что в нем можно улучшать.

По поводу "Расстрел памяти". IMHO очевидная паранойя. Мой подход прост, тот кто *передал* неправильные данные в функцию *низкого уровня*, тот и *виноват*.

В реальной жизни проверять **надо** *входные данные* по месту их поступления **извне** программы, а не аргументы функций.

Comment: если данные проверять извне, тогда будет эти проверки придется дублировать в каждой месте, где нужно вызвать. 
Чуточку паранойи никогда не мешает в нормальном коде, а не в академической задаче. Я считаю, что каждая функция должна либо выдавать  результат, либо говорить, что она его не может выдать. Конечно, 100% покрытия никто не дает.
В данной задаче лучше все таки было бы писать с индексами - код прозрачнее станет.
И ещё - не стоит путать "совершенный код" и "оптимизированный".
@rejie не нужно редактировать и добавлять кучу вопросов в один - ответы людей выглядят нелепо.

Comment: @KoVadim, я первые лет 10 работы, тоже примерно так (кстати, ведь во **всех** хороших книжках это пишут) про проверки данных думал. 

Потом понял, что реально библиотечный код *для важного заказчика* пишется очень редко. На самом деле (среди своих) намного лучше хорошенько проверить данные поближе к месту их возникновения (не вычисления !).

Ну, а в вопросе номер 3 от ТС, что можно проверить? Установить обработчик SIGSEGV и sigsetjmp()? Опять же зачем? Упала прога - это счастье - есть что искать и улучшать.

Проверять, что читаем цифры ASCII? Теоретически можно, но место и время...

Comment: @KoVadim, только сейчас обратил внимание на Ваш комментарий про "проверки **извне** программы".

Я имел в виду не проверки *перед каждым вызовом функции*, а проверку корректности данных при их чтении из файлов (терминала, сокета, аргументов командной строки ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Последний вариант с большей вероятностью будет быстрее - компилятор явно видит, что можно заменить на 4, а то и вообще инлайнить функцию.

1 и 2 должны в идеале также оптимизироваться до третьего. Но не факт, что компилятор осилит. Нужно смотреть асм-код.

Но на я не думаю, что у Вас в коде именно все так. Там наверное больше кода. Вот его и нужно смотреть. Но нужно понимать, что в большинстве случаев такие ручные оптимизации могут иногда обманывать компилятор и не он не сможет написать более эффективный код.

Но если расставлять приоритеты, то по скорости я бы отсортировал бы их так 3 >= 1 >= 2.

Comment: Меня всегда смущают высказывания типа "компилятор видит". Неизвестно, что каждый конкретный компилятор видит (если только вы не его разработчик).

Comment: я лично пользуюсь опытом и 7 чувством.

Comment: А вы можете дать гарантию, что конкретная версия компилятора автора будет работать так же, как и те, на которых основан ваш опыт?

Comment: а я не давал гарантий. все нужно проверять на месте. Смотреть внутрь. Но общие тенденции есть.

Answer (score 6):

Такие вопросы рождают у меня тревогу. ТС, а тебе не пофиг? Что ты хочешь выиграть?

Седые старцы завещали: сперва найди узкое место, потом оптимизируй. А твои намерения выдают грех преждевременной оптимизации.

Правильный ответ на твой вопрос: тот код, который выглядит более читаемо и понятно.

Comment: Дословно не помню, но кто-то из великих утверждал, что истинная эффективность программ определяется алгоритмами и адекватными им структурами данных.

Однако, представлять во что выливается код на языке высокого уровня никогда лишним не будет.

Answer (score 4):

Укажешь в флагах "оптимизировать", значит будет оптимизировать. В каждом конкретном случае, код может различаться, вплоть до того что будет упразднена сама функция и на каждый ее вызов будет вставлен опкод в виде одной инструкции:

```
mov кудатотам, 4
```

Comment: А как в VS2010 посмотреть asm код конкретной функции, поделитесь если не сложно!?

Comment: проще всего в IDA(http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA) запихнуть бинарник, собранный с флагами оптимизации. вы удивитесь, насколько код станет неузнаваем. с большей вероятностью там функции не будет, поэтому ориентируйтесь на логику, которую описывает дизассемблированый код (:

Comment: @vv2 Проще всего в [**Disassembly Window,**][1] особенно если учесть возможность трассироваться по `asm` коду, не теряя брейкпоинтов и имея исходный код под глазами. Ради просмотра ассемблерного листинга покупать `IDA` - это уж, простите, перебор.

[1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3cwf295

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, судя по вашим словам, вы видимо редко работали с хорошо оптимизированным кодом.Ну не будет там некоторых участков кода, в силу их упрощения и замены на оптимизированные варианты.Да будете видеть asm код, но он не будет иметь точного, пошагового соответствия сишному. IDA - личные предпочтения, да и покупать не нужно, есть бесплатные версии.[Freeware versions of IDA][1]


  [1]: http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml

Answer (score 4):

Не знаю, как в VS2010, а в Windows-XP MinGW gcc  сделал такой код

```
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ gcc -O3 -S opt.c 
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ gcc --version
gcc.exe (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
```

Код:

```
    .file   "opt.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
.globl _Function1
    .def    _Function1; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_Function1:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    $4, %eax
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
.lcomm Var.0,16
    .p2align 4,,15
.globl _Function2
    .def    _Function2; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_Function2:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    $4, %eax
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    popl    %ebp
    movl    %eax, Var.0
    movl    $4, %eax
    ret
    .p2align 4,,15
.globl _Function3
    .def    _Function3; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_Function3:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    $4, %eax
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

Из него следует, что варианты 1 и 3 одинаковы, а 2 медленнее, даже если выбросить очевидно лишнюю команду `mov 4, %eax` перед `ret` в Function2.

Интересно, зачем компилятор (при оптимизации !!!) создает пустой фрейм функции? Может быть для возможности "посмертного" анализа?

Comment: Еще раз обратите внимание (оптимизация !!!). Компилятор "выбросил" неиспользуемую переменную в варианте 1 (указатель стека не сдвигается). Поэтому варианты 1 и 3 стали одинаковыми.

Если в варианте 1 написать volatile int Var; то получим

    _Function1:
     pushl %ebp
     movl %esp, %ebp
     subl $4, %esp
     movl $4, -4(%ebp)
     movl -4(%ebp), %eax
     leave
     ret

Видите разницу? 

По поводу реального быстродействия. Надежно замерить в реальной системе (не эмулятор) такиой код **невозможно**.

Answer (score 2):

Первый вопрос уже более-менее разжевали. Мое мнение - 3 >= 1 > 2.

Второй вопрос: без разницы. При обращении по индексу "за кулисами" происходит тот же расчет адреса и разыменование.

Третий вопрос. Очень трудночитаемо. Лучше все это суммирование разбить на кусочки и складывать. На скорость не повлияет, но будет лучше читаться.

Четвертый вопрос. Вариант с else статистически будет быстрее. См. комментарий.

Comment: Я думаю, что 4.2 (с else) быстрее 4.1.

Желательно (для быстродействия) чтобы условие-1 выполнялось в среднем чаще, чем условие-2.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. В 4.1 всегда будет проверяться второе условие, а в 4.2 - если первое неверно.

Comment: На самом деле, современные компиляторы умеют оптимизировать взаимоисключающие условия. Так что вариант 4.1 сам превратится в 4.2 в том случае, если взаимоисключаемость условий можно выявить на этапе компиляции. Но вариант 4.2 всё равно лучше, поскольку читающему код человеку, сразу понятно, что выполнится лишь один из блоков кода.

Answer (score 0):

Достоверный ответ можно получить только замерив время выполнения в каждом из вариантов. Как бы вы не пытались рассуждать, результаты тестов на производительность чаще всего мало предсказуемы.

Comment: Так что же получается, программист должен оптимизировать свой код исходя не из своих знаний а от того что там в конце намудрит компиллятор?

Comment: Программист должен писать нормальный код, а не извращать так, что даже компилятор не может разобрать.

Comment: Да. В самом общем случае программист должен писать неоптимизированный хорошо читаемый и архитектурно подходящий код, затем делать профилирование, которое выявит наиболее медленные места, после чего уже заниматься оптимизацией, причем каждый раз проверять профайлером, а соптимизировал ли он вообще что-либо. Даже разные версии одного компилятора могут по-разному компилировать код и не сделав замеров нельзя быть уверенным в правильности рассуждений программиста.